How to access optimal solution pool?
I have the following code for a staff scheduling model:
import gurobipy as gu

# Sets and indices
nurses = range(1,101)
shifts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
days = [1]
time_intervals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# Parameters
requirements = {(1, 1): 11, (2, 1): 18, (3, 1): 22, (4, 1): 32, (5, 1): 28, (6, 1): 21,
                (1, 2): 11, (2, 2): 18, (3, 2): 22, (4, 2): 32, (5, 2): 28, (6, 2): 21,
                (1, 3): 11, (2, 3): 18, (3, 3): 22, (4, 3): 32, (5, 3): 28, (6, 3): 21,
                (1, 4): 11, (2, 4): 18, (3, 4): 22, (4, 4): 32, (5, 4): 28, (6, 4): 21,
                (1, 5): 11, (2, 5): 18, (3, 5): 22, (4, 5): 32, (5, 5): 28, (6, 5): 21,
                (1, 6): 11, (2, 6): 18, (3, 6): 22, (4, 6): 32, (5, 6): 28, (6, 6): 21,
                (1, 7): 11, (2, 7): 18, (3, 7): 22, (4, 7): 32, (5, 7): 28, (6, 7): 21}

A = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

costs = {1: 145, 2: 100, 3: 80, 4: 95, 5: 110, 6: 150}
model = gu.Model("Nurse")

# Decision variables
x = model.addVars(nurses, shifts, days, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="x")
y = model.addVars(nurses, days, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="y")

# Constraints
model.addConstrs(gu.quicksum(x[i, j, d] for j in shifts) == y[i, d] for i in nurses for d in days)
model.addConstrs(gu.quicksum(x[i, j, d] for j in shifts) <= 1 for i in nurses for d in days)
model.addConstrs(gu.quicksum(A[j-1][t-1]*x[i, j, d] for i in nurses for j in shifts) >= requirements[t, d] for t in time_intervals for d in days)
#model.addConstrs(x[i, 6, d] + x[i, 1, d+1] <= 1 for i in nurses for d in range(1, 7))
model.update()

# Objective function: Minimize costs
model.setObjective(gu.quicksum(gu.quicksum(costs[j] * x[i, j, d] for j in shifts) for i in nurses for d in days), gu.GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Solve
model.optimize()

# Values
lst = model.getAttr("X", x)

print(lst)

I would like to access the solution pool that contains all combinations of the $x$ values that yield the optimal solution, but I don't know how to do this. How do I set this up and how can I then save the final $x$ values as dict for all feasible solutions that ran the same optimal cell function value, for example?

I am trying to play around with an example that seems very similar to what you are looking for.
import gurobipy as gu
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

# Sets and indices
nurses = range(1,101)
shifts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
days = [1]
time_intervals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# Parameters
requirements = {(1, 1): 11, (2, 1): 18, (3, 1): 22, (4, 1): 32, (5, 1): 28, (6, 1): 21,
                (1, 2): 11, (2, 2): 18, (3, 2): 22, (4, 2): 32, (5, 2): 28, (6, 2): 21,
                (1, 3): 11, (2, 3): 18, (3, 3): 22, (4, 3): 32, (5, 3): 28, (6, 3): 21,
                (1, 4): 11, (2, 4): 18, (3, 4): 22, (4, 4): 32, (5, 4): 28, (6, 4): 21,
                (1, 5): 11, (2, 5): 18, (3, 5): 22, (4, 5): 32, (5, 5): 28, (6, 5): 21,
                (1, 6): 11, (2, 6): 18, (3, 6): 22, (4, 6): 32, (5, 6): 28, (6, 6): 21,
                (1, 7): 11, (2, 7): 18, (3, 7): 22, (4, 7): 32, (5, 7): 28, (6, 7): 21}

A = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

costs = {1: 145, 2: 100, 3: 80, 4: 95, 5: 110, 6: 150}
model = gu.Model("Nurse")

# Decision variables
x = model.addVars(nurses, shifts, days, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="x")
y = model.addVars(nurses, days, vtype=gu.GRB.BINARY, name="y")

# Constraints
model.addConstrs(gu.quicksum(x[i, j, d] for j in shifts) == y[i, d] for i in nurses for d in days)
model.addConstrs(gu.quicksum(x[i, j, d] for j in shifts) <= 1 for i in nurses for d in days)
model.addConstrs(gu.quicksum(A[j-1][t-1]*x[i, j, d] for i in nurses for j in shifts) >= requirements[t, d] for t in time_intervals for d in days)
#model.addConstrs(x[i, 6, d] + x[i, 1, d+1] <= 1 for i in nurses for d in range(1, 7))
model.update()

# Objective function: Minimize costs
model.setObjective(gu.quicksum(gu.quicksum(costs[j] * x[i, j, d] for j in shifts) for i in nurses for d in days), gu.GRB.MINIMIZE)

'''
Solution pool

'''
# Limit how many solutions to collect
model.setParam(GRB.Param.PoolSolutions, 2)
# Limit the search space by setting a gap for the worst possible solution
# that will be accepted
model.setParam(GRB.Param.PoolGap, 0.0)
# do a systematic search for the k-best solutions
model.setParam(GRB.Param.PoolSearchMode, 2)

# Optimize
model.optimize()
# Values
lst = model.getAttr("X", x)
print(lst)

model.setParam(GRB.Param.OutputFlag, 0)

# Status checking
status = model.Status
if status in (GRB.INF_OR_UNBD, GRB.INFEASIBLE, GRB.UNBOUNDED):
    print("The model cannot be solved because it is infeasible or unbounded")
    sys.exit(1)

if status != GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print(f"Optimization was stopped with status {status}")
    sys.exit(1)

    # Print best selected set
print("Selected elements in best solution:")
print("\t", end="")
for i in nurses:
  for j in shifts:
    for d in days:
      if x[i,j,d].X > 0.9:
        print(f" x{i,j,d}", end="")
print("")


# Print number of solutions stored
nSolutions = model.SolCount
print(f"Number of solutions found: {nSolutions}")


# Print objective values of solutions
for e in range(nSolutions):
  model.setParam(GRB.Param.SolutionNumber, e)
  print(f"{model.PoolObjVal:g} ", end="")
  if e % 15 == 14:
    print("")
print("")


# print fourth best set if available
if nSolutions >= 2:
  model.setParam(GRB.Param.SolutionNumber, 3)

  print("Selected elements in i-th optimal solution:")
  print("\t", end="")
  for i in nurses:
    for j in shifts:
      for d in days:
        if x[i,j,d].X > 0.9:
              print(f" x{i,j,d}", end="")
  print("")

and the output shows the following results:
Set parameter PoolSolutions to value 2
Set parameter PoolGap to value 0.1
Set parameter PoolSearchMode to value 2
Gurobi Optimizer version 11.0.2 build v11.0.2rc0 (linux64 - "Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS")

CPU model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz, instruction set [SSE2|AVX|AVX2]
Thread count: 1 physical cores, 2 logical processors, using up to 2 threads

Optimize a model with 206 rows, 700 columns and 2500 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x258a90f4
Variable types: 0 continuous, 700 integer (700 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [8e+01, 2e+02]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 3e+01]
Found heuristic solution: objective 7680.0000000
Presolve removed 100 rows and 0 columns
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolved: 106 rows, 700 columns, 1900 nonzeros
Variable types: 0 continuous, 700 integer (700 binary)
Found heuristic solution: objective 7350.0000000

Root relaxation: objective 7.270000e+03, 221 iterations, 0.00 seconds (0.00 work units)

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

*    0     0               0    7270.0000000 7270.00000  0.00%     -    0s

Optimal solution found at node 0 - now completing solution pool...

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |      Pool Obj. Bounds     |     Work
             |                    |   Worst                   |
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0          -    0      7350.00000 7270.00000  1.09%     -    0s
     0     0          -    0      7350.00000 7270.00000  1.09%     -    0s
     0     2          -    0      7350.00000 7270.00000  1.09%     -    0s

Explored 3 nodes (225 simplex iterations) in 0.04 seconds (0.00 work units)
Thread count was 2 (of 2 available processors)

Solution count 2: 7270 7270 
No other solutions better than 7270

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 7.270000000000e+03, best bound 7.270000000000e+03, gap 0.0000%
{(1, 1, 1): 0.0, (1, 2, 1): -0.0, (1, 3, 1): -0.0, (1, 4, 1): -0.0, (1, 5, 1): 1.0, (1, 6, 1): -0.0, (2, 1, 1): -0.0, (2, 2, 1): -0.0, (2, 3, 1): -0.0, (2, 4, 1): 1.0, (2, 5, 1): 0.0, (2, 6, 1): -0.0, (3, 1, 1): -0.0, (3, 2, 1): -0.0, (3, 3, 1): 0.0, (3, 4, 1): -0.0, (3, 5, 1): 1.0, (3, 6, 1): -0.0, (4, 1, 1): -0.0, (4, 2, 1): -0.0, (4, 3, 1): 1.0, (4, 4, 1): -0.0, (4, 5, 1): 0.0, (4, 6, 1): -0.0, (5, 1, 1): -0.0, (5, 2, 1): -0.0, (5, 3, 1): 0.0, (5, 4, 1): 1.0, (5, 5, 1): -0.0, (5, 6, 1): -0.0, (6, 1, 1): -0.0, (6, 2, 1): -0.0, (6, 3, 1): -0.0, (6, 4, 1): 0.0, (6, 5, 1): 1.0, (6, 6, 1): -0.0, (7, 1, 1): -0.0, (7, 2, 1): -0.0, (7, 3, 1): 1.0, (7, 4, 1): -0.0, (7, 5, 1): 0.0, (7, 6, 1): -0.0, (8, 1, 1): -0.0, (8, 2, 1): -0.0, (8, 3, 1): 1.0, (8, 4, 1): -0.0, (8, 5, 1): 0.0, (8, 6, 1): -0.0, (9, 1, 1): -0.0, (9, 2, 1): -0.0, (9, 3, 1): 1.0, (9, 4, 1): 0.0, (9, 5, 1): -0.0, (9, 6, 1): -0.0, (10, 1, 1): -0.0, (10, 2, 1): -0.0, (10, 3, 1): -0.0, (10, 4, 1): 1.0, (10, 5, 1): -0.0, (10, 6, 1): -0.0, (11, 1, 1): -0.0, (11, 2, 1): -0.0, (11, 3, 1): 1.0, (11, 4, 1): 0.0, (11, 5, 1): -0.0, (11, 6, 1): -0.0, (12, 1, 1): -0.0, (12, 2, 1): -0.0, (12, 3, 1): 1.0, (12, 4, 1): 0.0, (12, 5, 1): -0.0, (12, 6, 1): -0.0, (13, 1, 1): -0.0, (13, 2, 1): -0.0, (13, 3, 1): 1.0, (13, 4, 1): -0.0, (13, 5, 1): -0.0, (13, 6, 1): -0.0, (14, 1, 1): -0.0, (14, 2, 1): -0.0, (14, 3, 1): 1.0, (14, 4, 1): 0.0, (14, 5, 1): -0.0, (14, 6, 1): -0.0, (15, 1, 1): 0.0, (15, 2, 1): -0.0, (15, 3, 1): 1.0, (15, 4, 1): -0.0, (15, 5, 1): -0.0, (15, 6, 1): -0.0, (16, 1, 1): -0.0, (16, 2, 1): -0.0, (16, 3, 1): 1.0, (16, 4, 1): -0.0, (16, 5, 1): -0.0, (16, 6, 1): -0.0, (17, 1, 1): 1.0, (17, 2, 1): -0.0, (17, 3, 1): 0.0, (17, 4, 1): -0.0, (17, 5, 1): -0.0, (17, 6, 1): -0.0, (18, 1, 1): -0.0, (18, 2, 1): -0.0, (18, 3, 1): -0.0, (18, 4, 1): -0.0, (18, 5, 1): -0.0, (18, 6, 1): -0.0, (19, 1, 1): -0.0, (19, 2, 1): -0.0, (19, 3, 1): -0.0, (19, 4, 1): -0.0, (19, 5, 1): -0.0, (19, 6, 1): -0.0, (20, 1, 1): 1.0, (20, 2, 1): -0.0, (20, 3, 1): -0.0, (20, 4, 1): -0.0, (20, 5, 1): -0.0, (20, 6, 1): -0.0, (21, 1, 1): 0.0, (21, 2, 1): -0.0, (21, 3, 1): -0.0, (21, 4, 1): -0.0, (21, 5, 1): -0.0, (21, 6, 1): -0.0, (22, 1, 1): -0.0, (22, 2, 1): -0.0, (22, 3, 1): -0.0, (22, 4, 1): -0.0, (22, 5, 1): 1.0, (22, 6, 1): -0.0, (23, 1, 1): -0.0, (23, 2, 1): -0.0, (23, 3, 1): -0.0, (23, 4, 1): -0.0, (23, 5, 1): 1.0, (23, 6, 1): -0.0, (24, 1, 1): -0.0, (24, 2, 1): 0.0, (24, 3, 1): -0.0, (24, 4, 1): -0.0, (24, 5, 1): -0.0, (24, 6, 1): -0.0, (25, 1, 1): -0.0, (25, 2, 1): -0.0, (25, 3, 1): 1.0, (25, 4, 1): -0.0, (25, 5, 1): -0.0, (25, 6, 1): -0.0, (26, 1, 1): -0.0, (26, 2, 1): -0.0, (26, 3, 1): -0.0, (26, 4, 1): -0.0, (26, 5, 1): 1.0, (26, 6, 1): -0.0, (27, 1, 1): -0.0, (27, 2, 1): 0.0, (27, 3, 1): -0.0, (27, 4, 1): -0.0, (27, 5, 1): -0.0, (27, 6, 1): -0.0, (28, 1, 1): -0.0, (28, 2, 1): -0.0, (28, 3, 1): -0.0, (28, 4, 1): -0.0, (28, 5, 1): 1.0, (28, 6, 1): -0.0, (29, 1, 1): -0.0, (29, 2, 1): -0.0, (29, 3, 1): 1.0, (29, 4, 1): -0.0, (29, 5, 1): -0.0, (29, 6, 1): -0.0, (30, 1, 1): 0.0, (30, 2, 1): -0.0, (30, 3, 1): -0.0, (30, 4, 1): -0.0, (30, 5, 1): 1.0, (30, 6, 1): -0.0, (31, 1, 1): -0.0, (31, 2, 1): 1.0, (31, 3, 1): -0.0, (31, 4, 1): -0.0, (31, 5, 1): -0.0, (31, 6, 1): -0.0, (32, 1, 1): -0.0, (32, 2, 1): -0.0, (32, 3, 1): -0.0, (32, 4, 1): -0.0, (32, 5, 1): 0.0, (32, 6, 1): -0.0, (33, 1, 1): -0.0, (33, 2, 1): -0.0, (33, 3, 1): -0.0, (33, 4, 1): -0.0, (33, 5, 1): 0.0, (33, 6, 1): -0.0, (34, 1, 1): -0.0, (34, 2, 1): -0.0, (34, 3, 1): 1.0, (34, 4, 1): -0.0, (34, 5, 1): -0.0, (34, 6, 1): -0.0, (35, 1, 1): 1.0, (35, 2, 1): -0.0, (35, 3, 1): -0.0, (35, 4, 1): -0.0, (35, 5, 1): 0.0, (35, 6, 1): -0.0, (36, 1, 1): -0.0, (36, 2, 1): -0.0, (36, 3, 1): -0.0, (36, 4, 1): -0.0, (36, 5, 1): -0.0, (36, 6, 1): -0.0, (37, 1, 1): -0.0, (37, 2, 1): -0.0, (37, 3, 1): 1.0, (37, 4, 1): -0.0, (37, 5, 1): -0.0, (37, 6, 1): -0.0, (38, 1, 1): -0.0, (38, 2, 1): -0.0, (38, 3, 1): 0.0, (38, 4, 1): -0.0, (38, 5, 1): -0.0, (38, 6, 1): -0.0, (39, 1, 1): 1.0, (39, 2, 1): -0.0, (39, 3, 1): -0.0, (39, 4, 1): -0.0, (39, 5, 1): -0.0, (39, 6, 1): -0.0, (40, 1, 1): -0.0, (40, 2, 1): -0.0, (40, 3, 1): -0.0, (40, 4, 1): -0.0, (40, 5, 1): 0.0, (40, 6, 1): -0.0, (41, 1, 1): -0.0, (41, 2, 1): -0.0, (41, 3, 1): 1.0, (41, 4, 1): -0.0, (41, 5, 1): -0.0, (41, 6, 1): -0.0, (42, 1, 1): 1.0, (42, 2, 1): -0.0, (42, 3, 1): -0.0, (42, 4, 1): -0.0, (42, 5, 1): -0.0, (42, 6, 1): -0.0, (43, 1, 1): -0.0, (43, 2, 1): -0.0, (43, 3, 1): -0.0, (43, 4, 1): 0.0, (43, 5, 1): -0.0, (43, 6, 1): -0.0, (44, 1, 1): -0.0, (44, 2, 1): 0.0, (44, 3, 1): -0.0, (44, 4, 1): -0.0, (44, 5, 1): -0.0, (44, 6, 1): -0.0, (45, 1, 1): -0.0, (45, 2, 1): -0.0, (45, 3, 1): -0.0, (45, 4, 1): 0.0, (45, 5, 1): -0.0, (45, 6, 1): -0.0, (46, 1, 1): -0.0, (46, 2, 1): -0.0, (46, 3, 1): -0.0, (46, 4, 1): 0.0, (46, 5, 1): 1.0, (46, 6, 1): -0.0, (47, 1, 1): -0.0, (47, 2, 1): -0.0, (47, 3, 1): -0.0, (47, 4, 1): 0.0, (47, 5, 1): -0.0, (47, 6, 1): -0.0, (48, 1, 1): -0.0, (48, 2, 1): -0.0, (48, 3, 1): 0.0, (48, 4, 1): -0.0, (48, 5, 1): -0.0, (48, 6, 1): -0.0, (49, 1, 1): -0.0, (49, 2, 1): 0.0, (49, 3, 1): 1.0, (49, 4, 1): -0.0, (49, 5, 1): -0.0, (49, 6, 1): -0.0, (50, 1, 1): -0.0, (50, 2, 1): -0.0, (50, 3, 1): -0.0, (50, 4, 1): -0.0, (50, 5, 1): 1.0, (50, 6, 1): -0.0, (51, 1, 1): 0.0, (51, 2, 1): -0.0, (51, 3, 1): -0.0, (51, 4, 1): -0.0, (51, 5, 1): -0.0, (51, 6, 1): -0.0, (52, 1, 1): -0.0, (52, 2, 1): -0.0, (52, 3, 1): -0.0, (52, 4, 1): 0.0, (52, 5, 1): -0.0, (52, 6, 1): -0.0, (53, 1, 1): -0.0, (53, 2, 1): -0.0, (53, 3, 1): -0.0, (53, 4, 1): 0.0, (53, 5, 1): -0.0, (53, 6, 1): -0.0, (54, 1, 1): 1.0, (54, 2, 1): -0.0, (54, 3, 1): 0.0, (54, 4, 1): -0.0, (54, 5, 1): -0.0, (54, 6, 1): -0.0, (55, 1, 1): 0.0, (55, 2, 1): -0.0, (55, 3, 1): -0.0, (55, 4, 1): -0.0, (55, 5, 1): -0.0, (55, 6, 1): -0.0, (56, 1, 1): -0.0, (56, 2, 1): -0.0, (56, 3, 1): -0.0, (56, 4, 1): -0.0, (56, 5, 1): 0.0, (56, 6, 1): -0.0, (57, 1, 1): 0.0, (57, 2, 1): 1.0, (57, 3, 1): -0.0, (57, 4, 1): -0.0, (57, 5, 1): -0.0, (57, 6, 1): -0.0, (58, 1, 1): -0.0, (58, 2, 1): -0.0, (58, 3, 1): -0.0, (58, 4, 1): 0.0, (58, 5, 1): -0.0, (58, 6, 1): -0.0, (59, 1, 1): -0.0, (59, 2, 1): 0.0, (59, 3, 1): 1.0, (59, 4, 1): -0.0, (59, 5, 1): -0.0, (59, 6, 1): -0.0, (60, 1, 1): -0.0, (60, 2, 1): 1.0, (60, 3, 1): -0.0, (60, 4, 1): -0.0, (60, 5, 1): -0.0, (60, 6, 1): -0.0, (61, 1, 1): 1.0, (61, 2, 1): -0.0, (61, 3, 1): -0.0, (61, 4, 1): -0.0, (61, 5, 1): -0.0, (61, 6, 1): -0.0, (62, 1, 1): 1.0, (62, 2, 1): -0.0, (62, 3, 1): -0.0, (62, 4, 1): -0.0, (62, 5, 1): -0.0, (62, 6, 1): -0.0, (63, 1, 1): -0.0, (63, 2, 1): -0.0, (63, 3, 1): -0.0, (63, 4, 1): -0.0, (63, 5, 1): 1.0, (63, 6, 1): -0.0, (64, 1, 1): -0.0, (64, 2, 1): -0.0, (64, 3, 1): -0.0, (64, 4, 1): -0.0, (64, 5, 1): 1.0, (64, 6, 1): -0.0, (65, 1, 1): -0.0, (65, 2, 1): 1.0, (65, 3, 1): -0.0, (65, 4, 1): -0.0, (65, 5, 1): -0.0, (65, 6, 1): -0.0, (66, 1, 1): -0.0, (66, 2, 1): -0.0, (66, 3, 1): -0.0, (66, 4, 1): 0.0, (66, 5, 1): 1.0, (66, 6, 1): -0.0, (67, 1, 1): -0.0, (67, 2, 1): -0.0, (67, 3, 1): 1.0, (67, 4, 1): -0.0, (67, 5, 1): -0.0, (67, 6, 1): -0.0, (68, 1, 1): 1.0, (68, 2, 1): -0.0, (68, 3, 1): -0.0, (68, 4, 1): -0.0, (68, 5, 1): -0.0, (68, 6, 1): -0.0, (69, 1, 1): -0.0, (69, 2, 1): 1.0, (69, 3, 1): -0.0, (69, 4, 1): -0.0, (69, 5, 1): -0.0, (69, 6, 1): -0.0, (70, 1, 1): -0.0, (70, 2, 1): -0.0, (70, 3, 1): 0.0, (70, 4, 1): -0.0, (70, 5, 1): -0.0, (70, 6, 1): -0.0, (71, 1, 1): -0.0, (71, 2, 1): -0.0, (71, 3, 1): 1.0, (71, 4, 1): -0.0, (71, 5, 1): 0.0, (71, 6, 1): -0.0, (72, 1, 1): 0.0, (72, 2, 1): -0.0, (72, 3, 1): -0.0, (72, 4, 1): -0.0, (72, 5, 1): -0.0, (72, 6, 1): -0.0, (73, 1, 1): -0.0, (73, 2, 1): -0.0, (73, 3, 1): 1.0, (73, 4, 1): 0.0, (73, 5, 1): -0.0, (73, 6, 1): -0.0, (74, 1, 1): -0.0, (74, 2, 1): -0.0, (74, 3, 1): -0.0, (74, 4, 1): 1.0, (74, 5, 1): -0.0, (74, 6, 1): -0.0, (75, 1, 1): -0.0, (75, 2, 1): -0.0, (75, 3, 1): 0.0, (75, 4, 1): 1.0, (75, 5, 1): -0.0, (75, 6, 1): -0.0, (76, 1, 1): 0.0, (76, 2, 1): -0.0, (76, 3, 1): -0.0, (76, 4, 1): -0.0, (76, 5, 1): -0.0, (76, 6, 1): -0.0, (77, 1, 1): -0.0, (77, 2, 1): -0.0, (77, 3, 1): 1.0, (77, 4, 1): 0.0, (77, 5, 1): -0.0, (77, 6, 1): -0.0, (78, 1, 1): -0.0, (78, 2, 1): -0.0, (78, 3, 1): 1.0, (78, 4, 1): -0.0, (78, 5, 1): -0.0, (78, 6, 1): -0.0, (79, 1, 1): -0.0, (79, 2, 1): -0.0, (79, 3, 1): 0.0, (79, 4, 1): 1.0, (79, 5, 1): -0.0, (79, 6, 1): -0.0, (80, 1, 1): 1.0, (80, 2, 1): -0.0, (80, 3, 1): 0.0, (80, 4, 1): -0.0, (80, 5, 1): -0.0, (80, 6, 1): -0.0, (81, 1, 1): -0.0, (81, 2, 1): -0.0, (81, 3, 1): 0.0, (81, 4, 1): -0.0, (81, 5, 1): 1.0, (81, 6, 1): -0.0, (82, 1, 1): 0.0, (82, 2, 1): -0.0, (82, 3, 1): -0.0, (82, 4, 1): -0.0, (82, 5, 1): -0.0, (82, 6, 1): -0.0, (83, 1, 1): -0.0, (83, 2, 1): -0.0, (83, 3, 1): 0.0, (83, 4, 1): -0.0, (83, 5, 1): 1.0, (83, 6, 1): -0.0, (84, 1, 1): -0.0, (84, 2, 1): -0.0, (84, 3, 1): -0.0, (84, 4, 1): 1.0, (84, 5, 1): -0.0, (84, 6, 1): -0.0, (85, 1, 1): -0.0, (85, 2, 1): -0.0, (85, 3, 1): 1.0, (85, 4, 1): -0.0, (85, 5, 1): 0.0, (85, 6, 1): -0.0, (86, 1, 1): 1.0, (86, 2, 1): -0.0, (86, 3, 1): -0.0, (86, 4, 1): -0.0, (86, 5, 1): -0.0, (86, 6, 1): -0.0, (87, 1, 1): -0.0, (87, 2, 1): -0.0, (87, 3, 1): 1.0, (87, 4, 1): -0.0, (87, 5, 1): 0.0, (87, 6, 1): -0.0, (88, 1, 1): -0.0, (88, 2, 1): -0.0, (88, 3, 1): -0.0, (88, 4, 1): -0.0, (88, 5, 1): 0.0, (88, 6, 1): -0.0, (89, 1, 1): -0.0, (89, 2, 1): -0.0, (89, 3, 1): 1.0, (89, 4, 1): -0.0, (89, 5, 1): 0.0, (89, 6, 1): -0.0, (90, 1, 1): -0.0, (90, 2, 1): -0.0, (90, 3, 1): 0.0, (90, 4, 1): -0.0, (90, 5, 1): -0.0, (90, 6, 1): -0.0, (91, 1, 1): 0.0, (91, 2, 1): -0.0, (91, 3, 1): -0.0, (91, 4, 1): -0.0, (91, 5, 1): 1.0, (91, 6, 1): -0.0, (92, 1, 1): -0.0, (92, 2, 1): -0.0, (92, 3, 1): -0.0, (92, 4, 1): -0.0, (92, 5, 1): 1.0, (92, 6, 1): -0.0, (93, 1, 1): -0.0, (93, 2, 1): -0.0, (93, 3, 1): 0.0, (93, 4, 1): -0.0, (93, 5, 1): 1.0, (93, 6, 1): -0.0, (94, 1, 1): -0.0, (94, 2, 1): -0.0, (94, 3, 1): 0.0, (94, 4, 1): -0.0, (94, 5, 1): -0.0, (94, 6, 1): -0.0, (95, 1, 1): -0.0, (95, 2, 1): -0.0, (95, 3, 1): 0.0, (95, 4, 1): -0.0, (95, 5, 1): 1.0, (95, 6, 1): -0.0, (96, 1, 1): -0.0, (96, 2, 1): -0.0, (96, 3, 1): -0.0, (96, 4, 1): 0.0, (96, 5, 1): -0.0, (96, 6, 1): -0.0, (97, 1, 1): -0.0, (97, 2, 1): -0.0, (97, 3, 1): -0.0, (97, 4, 1): 0.0, (97, 5, 1): 1.0, (97, 6, 1): -0.0, (98, 1, 1): -0.0, (98, 2, 1): 1.0, (98, 3, 1): -0.0, (98, 4, 1): -0.0, (98, 5, 1): -0.0, (98, 6, 1): -0.0, (99, 1, 1): -0.0, (99, 2, 1): -0.0, (99, 3, 1): 0.0, (99, 4, 1): -0.0, (99, 5, 1): 1.0, (99, 6, 1): -0.0, (100, 1, 1): -0.0, (100, 2, 1): 1.0, (100, 3, 1): -0.0, (100, 4, 1): -0.0, (100, 5, 1): -0.0, (100, 6, 1): -0.0}
Selected elements in best solution:
     x(1, 5, 1) x(2, 4, 1) x(3, 5, 1) x(4, 3, 1) x(5, 4, 1) x(6, 5, 1) x(7, 3, 1) x(8, 3, 1) x(9, 3, 1) x(10, 4, 1) x(11, 3, 1) x(12, 3, 1) x(13, 3, 1) x(14, 3, 1) x(15, 3, 1) x(16, 3, 1) x(17, 1, 1) x(20, 1, 1) x(22, 5, 1) x(23, 5, 1) x(25, 3, 1) x(26, 5, 1) x(28, 5, 1) x(29, 3, 1) x(30, 5, 1) x(31, 2, 1) x(34, 3, 1) x(35, 1, 1) x(37, 3, 1) x(39, 1, 1) x(41, 3, 1) x(42, 1, 1) x(46, 5, 1) x(49, 3, 1) x(50, 5, 1) x(54, 1, 1) x(57, 2, 1) x(59, 3, 1) x(60, 2, 1) x(61, 1, 1) x(62, 1, 1) x(63, 5, 1) x(64, 5, 1) x(65, 2, 1) x(66, 5, 1) x(67, 3, 1) x(68, 1, 1) x(69, 2, 1) x(71, 3, 1) x(73, 3, 1) x(74, 4, 1) x(75, 4, 1) x(77, 3, 1) x(78, 3, 1) x(79, 4, 1) x(80, 1, 1) x(81, 5, 1) x(83, 5, 1) x(84, 4, 1) x(85, 3, 1) x(86, 1, 1) x(87, 3, 1) x(89, 3, 1) x(91, 5, 1) x(92, 5, 1) x(93, 5, 1) x(95, 5, 1) x(97, 5, 1) x(98, 2, 1) x(99, 5, 1) x(100, 2, 1)
Number of solutions found: 2
7270 7270 
Selected elements in i-th optimal solution:
     x(1, 5, 1) x(2, 4, 1) x(3, 5, 1) x(4, 3, 1) x(5, 4, 1) x(6, 5, 1) x(7, 3, 1) x(8, 3, 1) x(9, 3, 1) x(10, 4, 1) x(11, 3, 1) x(12, 3, 1) x(13, 3, 1) x(14, 3, 1) x(15, 3, 1) x(16, 3, 1) x(17, 1, 1) x(20, 1, 1) x(22, 5, 1) x(23, 5, 1) x(25, 3, 1) x(26, 5, 1) x(28, 5, 1) x(29, 3, 1) x(30, 5, 1) x(31, 2, 1) x(34, 3, 1) x(35, 1, 1) x(37, 3, 1) x(39, 1, 1) x(41, 3, 1) x(42, 1, 1) x(46, 5, 1) x(49, 3, 1) x(50, 5, 1) x(54, 1, 1) x(57, 2, 1) x(59, 3, 1) x(60, 2, 1) x(61, 1, 1) x(62, 1, 1) x(63, 5, 1) x(64, 5, 1) x(65, 2, 1) x(66, 5, 1) x(67, 3, 1) x(68, 1, 1) x(69, 2, 1) x(71, 3, 1) x(73, 3, 1) x(74, 4, 1) x(75, 4, 1) x(77, 3, 1) x(78, 3, 1) x(79, 4, 1) x(80, 1, 1) x(81, 5, 1) x(83, 5, 1) x(84, 4, 1) x(85, 3, 1) x(86, 1, 1) x(87, 3, 1) x(89, 3, 1) x(91, 5, 1) x(92, 5, 1) x(93, 5, 1) x(95, 5, 1) x(97, 5, 1) x(98, 2, 1) x(99, 5, 1) x(100, 2, 1)

I hope it helps.
